# Load product prices from multiple stores for every product into one array

Tags: magento-1.7, model, query

I need to load every product in Magento from two specific stores and collate the result into one array.

At the moment, I am doing it like this (`using app/mage.php`) and it's very slow:

```
public function getPrices($store_list)
{
    // Init
    $results = [];

    // Load Product Collection
    $product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection();

    // Iterate Through Collection
    foreach ($product_collection as $p)
    {
        // Load Retail Product
        $retail_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($store_list['Retail'])
            ->load($p->getId());
        $results[$retail_product->getSku()]['Retail'] = $retail_product->getPrice();

        // Load Trade Product
        $trade_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($store_list['Trade'])
            ->load($p->getId());
        $results[$trade_product->getSku()]['Trade'] = $trade_product->getPrice();
    }

    // Finished
    return $results;
}
```

Is there a way to speed this up by doing the data loading via a direct sql query?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this awesome article : http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/update-prices-sql/

I came up with the following query to load the data I needed in one go like this:

```
SELECT
    CPE.sku,
    CPED.`value` AS price,
    CPED.store_id
FROM
    bd_catalog_product_entity AS CPE
INNER JOIN bd_catalog_product_entity_decimal AS CPED ON CPED.entity_id = CPE.entity_id
WHERE
    CPED.attribute_id = (
        SELECT
            attribute_id
        FROM
            bd_eav_attribute eav
        WHERE
            eav.entity_type_id = 4
        AND eav.attribute_code = 'price'
    )
AND
    CPED.store_id IN (1, 2)
```

Where Store Id `#1` = `Retail` and #`2` = `Trade`

This query result appears to match what I am seeing in my Magento.

If this is wrong or can be improved, feel free to reply to my post. Thanks.